# Android, Internet & Sleep

Tags: android, wakelock

So I have a music app that continuously downloads data from a server and plays it back on the phone.

The problem:
After a few minutes the music stops, apparently because Android went to sleep and stops all data transfer. The connections aren't even closed, the reading Threads are simply paused. FYI, I am running this in a service which is running in foreground mode. I have also aquired a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`.

However, the partial wake lock only prevents the CPU from going to sleep, not the network connection. The solution seems to be to aquire a `FULL_WAKE_LOCK` which works but has the ugly side effect that the bright and energy hungry screen stays on.

It seems like major music apps (like Pandora) are doing the same thing.

So the question:
Is there a better way to get Android to keep the internet connection alive? Is there some way / workaround to achieve an `INTERNET_WAKE_LOCK`?

Comment: Why aren't you buffering?

Comment: The service can be killed anytime, are you sure its being restarted? A PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK should be sufficient for this...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html

Comment: I am buffering, but not the whole song (could be very large). I am aquiring a wake lock and the service is running in foreground mode. It is not being killed by the system. Only the network is...

Comment: I know this is old, but did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: I have successfully worked around it, but would not call it a "solution". Basically I am now buffering whole songs and am using GCM to 'tickle' the device if I need it to do anything.

Comment: @Daniel can you please post answer?

Answer (score 2):

there are two thing weak lock and wifimanager also you can use any of to prevent to sleep mode

```
PowerManager pm;
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock, wakeLock_deamScreen,wakeLock_Full_wake_lock;
WifiLock lock;
pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"SleepMode by pressing Power Button");
wakeLock.acquire();
wakeLock_deamScreen = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK| PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE| PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,"Screen Deam or screen stays on for a little longer");
wakeLock_deamScreen.acquire();
wakeLock_Full_wake_lock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK,"");
wakeLock_Full_wake_lock.acquire();

ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this,EyeSpyliteActivity.class);
PackageManager packagemanager = getPackageManager();
packagemanager.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
lock = wifiManager.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "LockTag");
lock.acquire();
```

And Dont forget to release it onDestroy

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
 lock.release();
 wakeLock.release();
 wakeLock_deamScreen.release();
 wakeLock_Full_wake_lock.release();
}
```

Comment: does the Wifi lock does also affect 3G / 4G connections?

Comment: that's i dont know for that you have to reaserch but onece you put wakeLock it's not requird

Comment: Which of those is enough for Internet alone?

Answer (score 0):

There are [`WifiLocks`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html) to prevent the network from going down. Use the [`WifiManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) to aquire one by [`createWifiLock`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#createWifiLock%28int,%20java.lang.String%29). Note that you should only use that locks when actually downloading, so the Wifi can go down while there is only playback (if that case applies to your application).

Comment: Does it also work for other ways to access the Internet (3g/4g...) ?